# Linq query that return N results from two grouped columns

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a table 'posts' with the following columns

```
- id (int)
- categoryId (int)
- itemVariant (sbyte)
- [... other post data columns..]
```

I'm trying to build a linq query that will result in a list that contains the **top N results of itemVariants in each categoryId**.

I tried:

```
   var res = (from o in db.posts
        where o.id == d.id 
        group o by new
          {
              o.categoryId,
              o.itemVariant
           } 

          into groups
          select groups).SelectMany(g => g.Take(n));
```

However, this returns one result per category. I think that I need two groupings and a subquery in it but don't know how to achieve this.

Example:

```
-Id: 2, categoryId: 1, itemVariant 1
-Id: 3, categoryId: 1, itemVariant 2
-Id: 4, categoryId: 1, itemVariant 1
-Id: 5, categoryId: 2, itemVariant 1
```

The query that returns TOP 1 items, should return two group of posts for each category, each group has two groups that represent the inner grouping by itemVariant, the one for category 2 and itemVariant 1 grouping will include row with Id=5. The category 1 group will include two groups (due to two itemVariant options), in the first group row Id=2 (or Id=4, depends on my ordering, but let's assume default ordering) and in the second group Id=3.

The returned grouping should have the following sample structure.

```
-  Grouped Category 1
  - Grouped ItemVariant 1
    - Post 1 data
    - Post 2 data
  - Grouped Item Variant 2
    - Post 3 data
- Grouped Category 2
  - Grouped itemVariant 1
    - Post 4 data
  - Grouped itemVariant 2
    - Post 5 data
```

The query can be in either Entity Framework  or Linq. Developing in Visual Studio 2015 / C# / MySQL.

Comment: Can you paraphrase what is the problem with your query? From what I see, it returns a single list containing at most N items from each category. What is the expected result?

Comment: @IvanStoev The problem is that that query doesn't take the itemVariant into account. For each category, I need to take the top N results for each itemVariant. So for example, For category 1 and 2, get the top 2 of itemVariant = 1 and itemVariant = 2. So extra grouping should be made I suppose than an inner 'Take' function that runs in the inner grouping to take the Top N results.

Comment: How about this `var res = (from o in db.posts
        where o.id == d.id 
        group o by new
          {
              o.categoryId,
              o.itemVariant.Take(n) //assuming this is a collection
           } 

          into groups
          select groups).SelectMany(g => g.Take(n));`

Comment: @Eldho " o.itemVariant.Take(1)" doesn't compile - 'invalid anonymous type member declerator' error.

Comment: @Eldho  Furhtermore, the Take(n) at the end will Take the top groups, not the inner itemVariant items I think.

Comment: `var res = (from o in db.posts
        where o.id == d.id 
        group o by new
          {
                categoryId= o.categoryId,
                varient = o.itemVariant.Take(n)
           } 

          into groups
          select groups);`

I think this will do

Comment: @Eldho In the question I've written that itemVariant is a column in a table and I gave an example with a number.

Comment: Sorry @IdanShechter i misunderstood the question

Comment: Still don't get it. Your query returns 3 items with the data from the example containing exactly what you described. It's flat list, is that the problem? You want some sort of nested groupings? What is the expected **structure** of the result?

Comment: @Eldho The query should group by categoryId first than by the itemVariant. In my query I grouped by them both, which lead to different results. I'll add the structure to the question in a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var result = db.posts.GroupBy(post => post.categoryId,
    (categoryId, categoryPosts) => new { categoryId,
        itemVariants = categoryPosts.GroupBy(post => post.itemVariant,
            (itemVariant, itemVariantPosts) => new { itemVariant,
                topPosts = itemVariantPosts.Take(n)
            })
    });
```

Comment: Champ 'Distinct1.categoryId' inconnu dans where clause

Comment: @IdanShechter What's that "iconnu dans"?

Comment: @IdanShechter So it's some sort of an error you are getting? Could you translate the whole "Champ 'Distinct1.categoryId' inconnu dans where clause". What where clause it's referring to - i don't have a where clause.

Comment: I try to run it in LINSQPad and it gives me: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<byte>' because it is not a delegate type" for post.itemVariant

Comment: Again, what I need it results that are first grouped by the category Id (tinyint column), then grouped by the itemVariant (tinyint column). Then I want to iterate over each category and than iterate over the group of each itemVariant and print the post's Id there.

Comment: @IdanShechter I'm close to take off. I don't care what LinqPad is doing, I'm running the above in Visual Studio against both enumerable and EF db context source, and it compiles and executes w/o problem.

Comment: OK, I'll look further into the code and recheck. thanks.

Comment: Visual studio gives: "Unknown column 'Distinct1.categoryId' in 'where clause'".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94959/discussion-between-ivan-stoev-and-idan-shechter).